# Formula for regression function based on intercept and two X points

Tags: self-study, regression-coefficients

This is from an assignment I need to finish but I need some **advice** on where/what  to investigate further please (absolutely new to stats):

---

You use regression to generate a function that operates on two variables (`X1` and `X2`) to predict a label (`Y`).

The regression output shows the following coefficients:

```
Intercept: 12.576
X1: 2.32
X2: -1.3
```

Which formulae describes the regression function?

```
Y = 12.567 + 2.32 + -1.3
Y = 12.567 + (X1 x 2.32) + (X2 x -1.3)
Y = 12.567 + (X1 + 2.32) + (X2 + -1.3)
```

---

My thinking :

```
sample regression line is: ŷ = b0 + b1x.

thus : y = 12.576 + (regression coefficient)

and regression coefficient = y = mx + b
```

I am out of my depth - please advise
[image]

Comment: Is this a multiple choice question? For the three choices you give, are you sure you copied these down correctly? Or have you maybe switched some plus and multiplication signs?

Comment: You should read the self-study tag wiki for details about the sort of information we might need to help you.

Comment: Thanks 5ayat1, I did have the last mcp incorrect. I fixed it and added screenshot. @mdewey I am really respectful to self-study - not asking for the answer as this will mess the next course up for me - just asking where I should be looking please

Comment: You need to decide first of all whether you think the coefficients multiply the variables or are added to them. So when you write the notation bx, does that mean b times x or b plus x?

Comment: OK so Im on the right path with the formula being ŷ = b0 + b1x at least. It means b times x. – should i focus on understanding how to get b1 from 2 coordinates? I see slope = regression coefficient.

Comment: Each variable has its own coefficient. Does that help?

Comment: Thanks mdewey, i'm then going with Y = 12.567 + (X1 x 2.32) + (X2 x -1.3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is: y = b0 + b1 x1 + b2 x2 + epsilon
The estimated model is: y= b0.hat + b1.hat x1 + b2.hat X2 with b0.hat=12.576, b1.hat=2.32, b2.hat=-1.3. So: y = 12.576 + 2.32 x1 -1.3 x2